# Why does Debian set a different PATH for root compared to other users? Why aren't `sbin` directories included for all users?

Tags: debian, path

On a fresh install of Debian 11 "Bullseye" using the net installer, intended to be used as a server, root has the following PATH:

```
root@debian:~# echo $PATH | tr : '\n'
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
```

Whereas any other user has the following PATH:

```
jivan@debian:~$ echo $PATH | tr : '\n'
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/local/games
/usr/games
```

This behaviour comes from a few lines at the start of `/etc/profile`:

```
if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
fi
export PATH
```

But why is this the default behaviour? Coming from Ubuntu Server, where all users have `/usr/sbin` and `/usr/local/sbin` in their PATH (those lines in `/etc/profile` that I mentioned aren't there in an Ubuntu install), this is jarring; I cannot run/autocomplete many commands that I would like to run as non-root. I've put a one-liner in `/etc/profile.d` to "fix" this, but I'm wondering why this is the default in the first place.

Comment: Irrespective of your question, my (old-school) opinion is that it is very wrong to have sbin dirs in root's $PATH. It makes admins lazy. Whenever I need to execute whatever as root, I always type in the absolute path. :-P

Comment: And in 40 years, I never broke any system for having confused with whatever other file holding an identical name. (This now being part of an answer to your question.)

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks, that definitely clears up the intention. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem that it's adhered to particularly well.

Comment: @MC68020 Do you really type out `/usr/bin/ls` whenever you need a directory listing as root? Do you modify any scripts that root runs so that they also use full directory paths? Both sound very tedious. And in my 40+ years as a sys admin, I never have broken any system for running identical executable names despite having `/sbin` in my path and not using full path names.

Comment: @doneal24 : Your success is certainly because you think & control everything prior to hit the return key. Congrats ! As a pianist, my fingers have always been far quicker than my brain therefore, the time needed to write /bin/rm /some_absolute_path helps me a lot to realize if this is actually what I want before having the pinkie on the return key. :-P No kidding, I can produce the root's bash history (of this desktop). Last command being */sbin/lilo -C /etc/lilo.conf* and yes indeed I know that /etc/lilo.conf is default.

Comment: @MC68020 I am also a pianist and type at 100 wpm. Add autocomplete and reverse-search to that and I can easily get through many commands in seconds. I just scrupulously read back what I've typed before I hit enter if it's a risky/important action. Needing to type `/sbin/` before many commands isn't helping you; just put `/sbin` at the front of your PATH. Who is putting anything called `lilo` in places like `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/sbin`, or `~/bin` anyway? I would argue that your practice offers a false sense of security. If anyone tampers with `/sbin`, you're equally as screwed as I am.

Comment: @doneal24 For the record, I do use absolute paths in scripts, because $PATH may have changed between script creation and execution. That is a potential cause of bugs down the line. I do this via variables though so that I don't have to write out the full path every time I use it in the script, e.g. `command=/usr/local/sbin/command; $command arg1 arg2`.

Comment: @JivanPal For scripts that  I write I tend to put an explicit `PATH=` at the beginning of the script so I know I'm only searching in a very limited number of directories. I trust that `/usr/sbin`, `/usr/bin`, and `/usr/local/bin` are safe. If I need an executable outside of that path then I will put in the full pathname. I am not a pianist but after this many years I still have finger memory on way too many commands. Typing a `sed` regex is easy, typing a word document with arbitrary text makes me think.

Answer (score 1):

From the [FileSystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s16.html):

> 3.16. /sbin : System binaries
> 3.16.1. Purpose Utilities used for system administration (and other root-only commands) are stored in /sbin, /usr/sbin, and
> /usr/local/sbin.

So we can see that `/sbin` (and friends) should only have admin level commands that may need `root` to run properly.  Your normal user doesn't need them, and may get errors if they try to run them.

On a machine only used by a single user who has admin permissions (e.g. via `sudo`) then it may make sense to add these directories as you have.  On a multi-user machine with admins and non-admins then it may make sense for the admins to modified their own `$HOME/.profile`.

Comment: Why does it matter if system commands like `adduser` are in all users' PATH? The non-privileged ones can't run them successfully anyway.

Comment: Why clutter up the user environment with commands they'll get errors from?  There's also a minor performance increase from not having unnecessary directories on the path (`execlp()`etc search all the directories looking for a match).

Comment: As I suggest in some OP's comment, I think there is also some "idiot-proof" reason. Users can give whatever name to their executable in their home. And since pwd is not part of their $PATH, In case the filename matches some sbin executable and, of course, they forget the leading ./ then…

Comment: @MC68020 Then what? They run the system command, and either they are privileged enough to do so, or they are not.

Comment: @StephenHarris There are commands in `/usr/sbin` that can very well be run by non-root anyway, e.g. `visudo`, `validlocale`... This discovery/question was actually prompted by me being bit in the butt trying to run `nginx -V` and seeing `nginx: command not found`, making me wonder why Nginx was apparently not installed on my system despite me having definitely done so. Any latency benefit from not searching `/usr/sbin` has got to be negligible.

Comment: Heck, even `traceroute` is in `/usr/sbin` for some reason, as well as in `/usr/bin`. Granted, both are ultimately symlinks to `/usr/bin/traceroute.db`, but why have both of those symlinks anyway? This packaging choice is strange... Ubuntu just has `/usr/bin/traceroute` as the actual binary and that's that.